# probability question on balls of five different labels

Tags: probability-distribution

I have five different balls with labels A,B,C,D,E . I want to draw three balls at a time. The number of ways I can do it will be 5 c 3 that would be 10. But I want to know in how many ways I can take set of these balls in which one ball would be with specific label. For suppose 'C'. i got answer from one site that it will be 6 ways. But I want to know the general formula. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure it out this way. As I always want C in my set of three balls.. That means in super set of 5 balls.. i am excluding C.  out of 4 remaining balls i should get 2 balls each time. this i can do it by 4 c 2 which is equal to 6.